# Good resource for getting up to speed on windows forms development

Tags: winforms

I'm a .NET developer comfortable with C# and web application development.  I need to improve my knowledge of Winforms.  What is a good book or online resource that particularly covers the Winforms life cycle.  Which events to use for what?  How does OnLoad compare to Form_load etc.

Comment: Looks a lot like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357545/book-recommendation-for-winforms-design-programming

Comment: Are you aware of WPF? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

Comment: @codeworks - yes, we have a large existing codebase.  I need to learn how to maintain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned WinForm by myself without reading any book so basically I used a lot of web sites as source of information.

I'd suggest the following:

**MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com**

This is not only an API documentation site. They have some serious articles explaining a lot of they key concepts behind their technology. But of course the API documentation comes in handy a lot!

**The Official WPF and Windows Forms site: http://windowsclient.net/**

A bunch of articles and blogs talking about WPF and Windows Forms. Very entertaining when you simply don't know what you want to read. Pick anything.

**Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/**

I recommend this site because there are a lot of interesting projects with in depth details from the author plus you get to ask questions (or see what questions were asked). I found very good code examples in this web site that helped me to understand lots of different concepts (I'm not advocating you should copy any of their source code though).

**Stack Overflow: [I'll let you guess how to get there]**

It helps you to answer those quick questions on how to do certain things or why this is not working. Also very helpful to understand some cryptic behaviors or error messages that you'll see along the way.